# How can I use computer 1's webcam on computer 2's videoconference program (e.g., Skype)?

Tags: windows, skype, webcam

How can I use computer 1's webcam on computer 2's videoconference program (e.g., Skype)? Computer 1 runs Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and computer 2  runs Microsoft Windows 10 18.03 x64 Professional.

Both computers can run a videoconference program, and both computers are connected to the internet. The computers are not the same LAN (they are located in different countries).

Comment: Can the "Needs details or clarity" close voter please ask what they want me to detail/clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [USB over Network](https://www.usb-over-network.org/usb-network-gate/). This software will allow you to share webcam in LAN.

a workaround solution without third party software I can think now is to connect both computers to same network, allow remote desktop host on the computer which will share webcam, connect to that computer from the computer which will use webcam using Remote desktop, then in the webcam host use a software to view screen region of webcam. Softwares like Skype or Zoom will easily let you share your screen, so turn on screen sharing there. And Skype calls can be recieved or sent without webcam and when you start sharing screen place the webcam host towards you to place it.

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted. I've posted the question with a more focused scope: [How can I forward my computer's webcam to a remote computer so that programs on the remote computer can view it as if it was a local webcam?](https://superuser.com/q/1578319/116475)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the situation, but this sounds rather simple.

You can install Skype on computer 1 and then join the same (group)call as computer 2 is in. You would then have video from computer 1 and audio from computer 2.

Answer (score 1):

Set-up a meeting on https://meet.jit.si/ with computer 1 and computer 2 joining.
Settings in Jitsi for the machines would be:

- Computer 1: video on, audio off
- Computer 2: video off, audio off

Now join the Skype call with computer 2 and share the Jitsi window, which should be showing the computer 1 webcam.