# How can I forward my computer's webcam to a remote computer so that programs on the remote computer can view it as if it was a local webcam?

Tags: windows, skype, webcam

How can I forward my computer's webcam to a remote computer so that videoconference programs (e.g., Skype) on the remote computer can view it as if it was a local webcam (i.e., the webcam should show up in the webcam list on the videoconference programs on the remote computer)?

My computer runs Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and the remote computer runs Microsoft Windows 10 18.03 x64 Professional. Both computers are connected to the internet. The computers are not the same LAN (they are located in different countries).

Comment: That is probably not practical.  "Forwarding" the camera means you give access to the overseas machine to your computer in order to use the camera. That could be a security risk. It might be just as simple to get a camera overseas.

Comment: @John the camera overseas won't see me.

Comment: The overseas computer will need to see the machine the camera is connected to. Cameras are just a peripheral device without a lot of smarts (computing ) built in.

Comment: @John thanks that's ok, I do remote connections all the time.

Comment: As long as your connections are secure, then no issue. It still seems to me that cameras are very inexpensive so I just equip each computer with one.

Comment: @John the issue is that the camera located next to the remote computer wouldn't see me. That's why I want to forward the video feed from my local camera to the remote computer.

Comment: Have you seen [this?](https://www.usb-over-network.org/share-usb-webcam/)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I also recommended it in the previous question of OP in my answer, still this is not quite working as the webcams are overseas!